The program aborts when realloc() called more than 16 times
When the input string is longer than 16 characters the program aborts, but when I remove realloc and call malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000) instead it works perfectly
valgrind says
valgrind: mmap(0x17a000, 708608) failed in UME with error 22 (Invalid argument). valgrind: this can be caused by executables with very large text, data or bss segments.
but the string is allocated on the heap
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *getstr()
{
    char *buf = malloc(sizeof(char));

    if (buf == 0)
        return 0;

    size_t i = 0;
    int tmp;

    while (1)
    {
        if (i == SIZE_MAX)
        {
            errno = ERANGE;
            buf[i] = 0;
            return buf;
        }
        tmp = getchar();
        switch (tmp)
        {
            case EOF:
            case '\n':
                buf[i] = 0;
            case 0:
                return buf;
        }
        buf[i] = tmp;

        if (realloc(buf, ++i) == 0)
        {
            free(buf);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char *str = getstr();

    if (str == 0)
        return 1;

    printf("%s\n", str);
    free(str);
    return 0;
}

It works when I type
abcdefg
but crashes when I type something
like
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890

Please read the realloc documentation.  realloc(buf, ++i) potentially leaves buf as a dangling pointer -- you need to use the value returned by realloc.

The pointer buf in realloc(buf, ++i) is always invalidated and it's undefined behavior to use it, whether or not the reallocation was in-place. You have to write buf = realloc(buf, ++i) (or something more tedious if you want to free the memory in case the realloc failed).

Thank you, now it doesn't crash, but the string size limit is 16 characters.

You call realloc(buf,++i). What is i for the very first time this happens?

@Displayname "but the string size limit is 16 characters": what does that mean exactly? What exactly happens when you do what?

if (realloc(buf, ++i) == 0) fails to use the return value of realloc().
This results in undefined behavior (UB) when the old buf is used.

It is reasonable to assume that the return value differs after about the 16th call as the first call, under the hood, malloc(sizeof(char)) allocates maybe  16 characters.
Instead, use the return value.
// if (realloc(buf, ++i) == 0) {
void *new_ptr = realloc(buf, ++i);
if (new_ptr == 0) {
  free(buf);
  return 0;
}
buf = new_ptr;


Other issues exist, yet to get OP re-started.

First you should add “break;” in each “case” you have. Second where you do realloc you’re code should Look like this
if((buff = realloc(buff, (++i) * sizeof(char))) == 0) 

. For a improved Option of the code you should use some allocation strategy, becouse now you alloc ellements one by one. You should either alloc using predefined chunks of a specific size, either use an allocation strategy like this :
 if(max_space >= 4){
    max_space = (max_space / 2) *  3)
 }
 else{
    max_space++;
 } 

Now you should only check if i == max_space
This means that you filled all spaces.
By using this method, you memory will grow, but not too fast, and it will alloc only a few more spaces than needed sometimes. For example first 4 interations you have : “1, 2, 3, 4”, after this you have : “6, 9, 12, 18, 27, 39”.Maybe at the end if you want to save space you can do
  buff = realloc(buff, (i * sizeof(char)));

and by doing this when you return the string it will use only the space that you need, without allocation each time.
But for you’re max space 16 characters strig, you might get better off by using a normal array declared in int main. You should use alloc when you need a dynamic array, and you don’t know the max size, or the size is huge, like 1000000 elements. For example when you have to register each customer in an array. You don’t know the max number of customers here So you will use the dynamic array.
With the array declared in int main you re code should Look Like this :
int getStr(char *str_buffer)
{
   //you’re code for string
   //return 0 if max size exceded else 1
}
int main(void)
{
   char buffer[16];
   if(getStr(buffer) == 0){
     printf(“Read failed”);
   }
   return 0;
}


 


Let's look at the first two error. (Always start with the first errors reported).
==4907== Invalid write of size 1
==4907==    at 0x2019F9: getstr (so18.c:33)
==4907==    by 0x201A53: main (so18.c:45)
==4907==  Address 0x5460041 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1 free'd
==4907==    at 0x4852371: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:1807)
==4907==    by 0x201A10: getstr (so18.c:35)
==4907==    by 0x201A53: main (so18.c:45)
==4907==  Block was alloc'd at
==4907==    at 0x484D2E4: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:450)
==4907==    by 0x2018D1: getstr (so18.c:8)
==4907==    by 0x201A53: main (so18.c:45)


"Invalid write" means that you are trying to write to somewhere that you should not. The next two parts of the message explain what is going on.
"0 bytes after" means that it is immediately after some allocation.
"block of size 1 free'd ... by realloc" means that a call to realloc was responsible for the deallocation.
"Block was alloc'd ... at malloc" means that the deallocated block was originally allocated by malloc.

Matching that to your code

buf gets assigned a pointer to a block of 1 byte allocated by malloc at the start of getstr.
One character is read by getcharwhich gets written to that 1 byte block.
realloc is called but as said in the other answers the result is not assigned to buf. That means that buf now points to a free'd 1 byte block (and the 2 byte block allocated by realloc has leaked).
Next iteration. A second character is read by getchar and written to buf[1]. That's immediately after a block of size 1 that was free'd by realloc.

I'll get back to this later.
Then there is
==4907== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==4907==    at 0x4852371: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:1807)
==4907==    by 0x201A10: getstr (so18.c:35)
==4907==    by 0x201A53: main (so18.c:45)
==4907==  Address 0x5460040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1 free'd
==4907==    at 0x4852371: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:1807)
==4907==    by 0x201A10: getstr (so18.c:35)
==4907==    by 0x201A53: main (so18.c:45)
==4907==  Block was alloc'd at
==4907==    at 0x484D2E4: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:450)
==4907==    by 0x2018D1: getstr (so18.c:8)
==4907==    by 0x201A53: main (so18.c:45)


"Invalid free" means you are trying to deallocate something that you shouldn't.
"0 bytes inside a block of size 1 free'd ... realloc" like the previous one but this time the pointer is to the start of the block.
"Block was alloc'd ... at malloc" same as previously.

Continuing matching that to the code.

A second call to realloc tries to deallocate the 1 byte block again.

This second error is very serious. It means that from this point on the heap is corrupt. Usually that means that your executable is going to crash.
Getting back to that first error. Why doesn't a write after the block of 1 byte not cause a crash straight away? That's because there is a minimum size for heap allocations. It depends on the libc that you are using, but typically it is 8 or 16 bytes. It's hard coded into Valgrind so there is no command line option to change it.
This is probably why you don't get a crash until the string length reaches 16.
